# Add a field to multiple feature classes

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3

I am trying to add a field to a specific number of feature classes, the names of the feature classes are `Pumpcapacities_1`, `Pump capacities_2`, `Pump capacities_3`.

Each one of these feature classes are located in the same geodatabase, my idea was to use `arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("Pump*","Point")` in order to select only the feature classes that start with Pump. But it's not working, each one of those feature classes are in a different feature dataset.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\mviera\Documents\CWADigitizeSchemaWorking.gdb"
Feature = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("Pump*","Point")
for dataset in Feature
    arcpy.AddField_management(dataset, "INDPumpCapacity","TEXT",50,"","","IND Pump Capacity","NULLABLE","NON_REQUIRED")
    print dataset
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  A question asking for help with code should include a tested code attempt, as *text* rather than an image, with details about what happens when you run the code.  Please **[edit]** your question to replace your image with a text code snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using arcpy.ListFeatureClasses, since you already know the feature classes which you want to add a field to, you can just create a list which stores their names and iterate through the list:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\Users\\mviera\\Documents\\CWADigitizeSchemaWorking.gdb"
FcList = ["Pumpcapacities_1", 
          "Pump capacities_2", 
          "Pump capacities_3"]
for fc in FcList:
    arcpy.management.AddField(fc,"INDPumpCapacity","TEXT",50,"","","IND Pump Capacity", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED")
    print fc
```

Comment: Great, my pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through your Feature Datasets first.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\mviera\Documents\CWADigitizeSchemaWorking.gdb"

datasets = arcpy.ListDatasets(feature_type = 'Feature')
datasets = [''] + datasets if datasets is not None else []

for ds in datasets:
    Feature = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("Pump*", "Point", ds)
    for fc in Feature:
        arcpy.AddField_management(fc, "INDPumpCapacity", "TEXT", 50, "", "", "IND Pump Capacity")
        print fc
```

This was based on the code sample at the bottom of [ListFeatureClasses - ArcGIS Desktop help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/listfeatureclasses.htm)